# Time Slot search

Tags: python, pandas, time, lookup

Following my first question on this post I'm still trying to improve my code.

To express myself better my goal is to find the closest "time slot" to a given date.

"Time slots" represent opening times of my "factory" (weekends and holidays are therefore excluded).

```
     Date          start_time              end_time     
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
 2017-01-02 |   2017-01-02 07:00:00    2017-01-02 17:00:00   
 2017-01-03 |   2017-01-03 07:00:00    2017-01-03 17:00:00      
 2017-01-04 |   2017-01-04 07:00:00    2017-01-04 17:00:00  
 2017-01-05 |   2017-01-05 08:00:00    2017-01-05 17:00:00  
 2017-01-06 |   2017-01-06 08:00:00    2017-01-06 17:00:00 
 2017-01-09 |   2017-01-09 08:00:00    2017-01-09 17:00:00 
  .....     |        ......
```

This data is stored in a 740 lines table (which is my opening planning schedule for two years)

Trying to keep it simple I receive orders from clients and have to check when I can execute them.

For example an order received on `'2017-01-02 10:00:00'` can be treated without delay.
An order received on `'2017-01-02 17:30'` will have to wait until `'2017-01-03 07:00'` to be treated.

The same if the order is received on a weekend :
`'2017-01-07 17:30'` --> `'2017-01-09 07:00'`

I have to check thousands of orders regularly in an optimization algorithm and I'm looking for the best possible way for this search.

I started to implement a code using a Panda table but it was quite slow (code below).

I then used numpy arrays to speed up (and it worked fine) but it is still slow.

Going further in my searches I used sqlite but not with great results.

Therefore if any experienced advice could be given it would be of great help !

Thanks

PS: I did my best for the editing of this old post. Hope it is not confusing...

<s>I'm building up a production schedule for my factory and I wrote it using Python and Pandas.</s>

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains the working hours (and days of work) of my employees.

[Working hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxlLr.png)

On another hand, I have machines which work 24/7.

What I'm looking is to built a function that with a given date gives me the date on which my employee can start a new job (and also when his day will finish). Infact machine can stop a production at night but will have to wait the next morning (or next opening day) until someone can launch a new production on it.

For example :

```
opening_hours(2017-04-06 04:00:00)   -- > 2017-04-06 07:00:00,  2017-04-06 17:00:00 

opening_hours(2017-04-06 22:00:00)   -- > 2017-04-06 07:00:00, 2017-04-06 17:00:00

opening_hours(2017-04-07 22:00:00)   -- > 2017-04-10 07:00:00, 2017-04-10 17:00:00 *
*(because it is a weekend and the employee will be back on monday)
```

So far I wrote the following function but it is awfully slow :)

`def opening_hours(x):

        staff_working_time_start = df_staff_planning[df_staff_planning[u'Start time'] >= x][u'Start time'].min()
        staff_working_time_end =  df_staff_planning[df_staff_planning[u'End time'] >= x][u'End time'].min()
        if staff_working_time_end <= staff_working_time_start:
            staff_working_time_start = x
        return staff_working_time_start, staff_working_time_end`


<s>The function returns both the start working time of the day and the end time.</s>

It is ok for evaluating few dates but since I'm doing a lot of iterations (>5000) for my calculations, it is quite slow.

I thank you very much in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

finally found an interesting solution using bisect :

```
start = df_staff_planning[u'Start time'].tolist()
end = df_staff_planning[u'End time'].tolist()

def opening_hours_2(x):
   staff_working_time_start = start[bisect.bisect(start, a)]
   staff_working_time_end = end[bisect.bisect(end, a)]
   if staff_working_time_end <= staff_working_time_start:
        staff_working_time_start = x

   return staff_working_time_start, staff_working_time_end
```

It turns out to be 75x faster on my issue...